# How to use bootstrap style in meteor-react?

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs, meteor-react

I installed bootstrap package with command:

```
 meteor add twbs:bootstrap
```

And I made some example codes, but it does not work. Bootstrap style is not applied to button.

App.jsx

```
import React from 'react';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <button class="btn btn-info">Button</button>
    );
  }
}
```

Could you help me, please? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use className attribute instead of class.

Comment: Thank you so much!